# Add unique constraint on fields from different tables

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate

I have two tables/entities:

One table Users with these 3 fields :
id | login | external_id

There is a unique constraint on external_id but not on login

And another table User_Platforms that have these 3 fields :
id | user_id | platform_name

There is a @OneToMany relation between Users and Platforms. ( One user can have multiple platforms).
Is there a way to put a unique constraint on the fields login ( from Users table) and platform_name ( from User_Platforms table) to avoid having multiple users with the same login on the same platform ?

I was thinking of duplicating login field inside User_Platforms table to be able to do it easily. Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNIQUE` constraints cannot span multiple tables. In the model you are presenting "as is" it's not possible to create a unique constraint that will ensure data quality.

However, if you are willing to add redundancy to the data model you can enforce the rule. You'll need to add the column `login` as a redundant copy in the second table. This will change the way you insert data in the second table, but will ensure data quality.

For example:

```
create table users (
  id int primary key not null,
  login varchar(10) not null,
  external_id varchar(10) not null,
  constraint uq1 unique (id, login)
    -- extra UNIQUE constraint for redundancy purposes
);

create table user_platforms (
  id int primary key not null,
  user_id varchar(10) not null,
  platform_name varchar(10) not null,
  login varchar(10) not null, -- new redundant column
  constraint fk1 foreign key (id, login) references users (id, login),
    -- FK ensures that the redundancy doesn't become stale
  constraint uq2 unique (platform_name, login) -- finally, here's the prize!
);
```